# Order a complex MySql Query

Tags: mysql

I have this complex Sql query that i cannot order as i wish.

**Query**

```
$query = "SELECT *
            FROM element_skanning yt1 JOIN
                 (SELECT objekt_nr, element_nr
                  FROM element_skanning
                  WHERE vart IN ('B.Avf', 'R.Avf')
                  GROUP BY objekt_nr, element_nr
                  HAVING count(*) > 1
                 ) yt2
                  ON yt2.objekt_nr = yt1.objekt_nr AND
                     yt2.element_nr = yt1.element_nr 
            WHERE vart IN ('B.Avf', 'R.Avf')
            ORDER BY 2;";
```

I´d like it to order with: element_nr ASC

I tried difrent stuff like:

```
WHERE vart IN ('B.Avf', 'R.Avf')
GROUP BY objekt_nr, element_nr
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY element_nr ASC
```

or:

```
WHERE vart IN ('B.Avf', 'R.Avf')
GROUP BY objekt_nr, element_nr
ORDER BY 2 ASC
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

The main query ORDER BY 2 at the end. and this is element_nr
but all the data isnt ordered.

Why?

Comment: post your tables structure, sample of data source and expected result. Or ideally provide sqlfiddle

Comment: ...and show us your desired output.

Comment: Why you have `WHERE vart IN ('B.Avf', 'R.Avf')` in the outer `SELECT` when the same is in the subselect?

Comment: instead of using number in order by use the column_name with qualifier...it will order as required .... ORDER BY yt2.element_nr ASC

Comment: @narendra Perfect! Your comment works perfectly whitout me adding any more data! Please write this as an answear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is always advisable to use the column name (instead of positional value) in the order by clause to avoid any issues due to re-arranging columns (due to new additions or removals of columns), try as below..

```
$query = "SELECT *
        FROM element_skanning yt1 JOIN
             (SELECT objekt_nr, element_nr
              FROM element_skanning
              WHERE vart IN ('B.Avf', 'R.Avf')
              GROUP BY objekt_nr, element_nr
              HAVING count(*) > 1
             ) yt2
              ON yt2.objekt_nr = yt1.objekt_nr AND
                 yt2.element_nr = yt1.element_nr 
        WHERE vart IN ('B.Avf', 'R.Avf')
        ORDER BY yt2.element_nr;";
```